# Strikeout text in Select option

Tags: html, css

I am trying to strikeout the text in select option but, for some reason it is not working.

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/95/

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option value="1" class="strikeout text-style">Some Text 1</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="true">Some Text 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="strikeout text-style">Some Text 3</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
.strikeout {text-decoration:line-through;}
.text-style {color:blue;}
```

The color is getting applied but not the text-decoration. Am I missing anything? Any suggestions in appreciated.

**Expectation:**

The option 'Some Text 1' and 'Some Text 3' should be striked out.

Comment: It is working in Firefox (partially), not in Chrome, btw. By partially - i mean: line-through is not applied when element is selected, just on dropdown click....

Answer (score 4):

that will take much more lines of code and effort, you also will need to use a JQuery and bootstrap.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.option li', function () {
    var i = $(this).parents('.select').attr('id');
    var v = $(this).children().text();
    var o = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + i + ' .selected').attr('id', o);
    $('#' + i + ' .selected').text(v);
});
$(".disabledM").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:20px;
}
.select button {
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
.select .sel {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.select:last-child>.btn {
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
.selected {
    padding-right:10px;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    
}
.option {
    width:100%;
}
a.disabled-link,
a.disabled-link:visited ,
a.disabled-link:active,
a.disabled:hover {
    background-color:#d9d9d9 !important;
    color:#aaa !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group-btn select" id="select1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><span class="selected"></span>  <span class="sel"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu option" role="menu">
        <li><s>Some Text 1</s>
        </li>
        <li class="disabledM">Some Text 2</li>
        <li><s>Some Text 3</s>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion. +1 from me as well. I will try to implement this logic in my application.

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```css
.strikeout {
  color: blue;
}

.sel:first-child{
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<select class='sel'>
    <option value="1" class="strikeout text-style">Some Text 1</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="true">Some Text 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="strikeout text-style">Some Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: "The option 'Some Text 1' and 'Some Text 3' should be striked out." is a direct quote from his question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, as Adam said, the option 'Some Text 1' and 'Some Text 3' should be striked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using uni-code like this lol:  https://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/6225/
Just convert your text to uni-code like from this place http://manytools.org/facebook-twitter/strikethrough-text/ and paste the text back into your html haha

**html**

```
<select>
    <option value="1" class="strikeout text-style">S̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶T̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶1̶</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="true">Some Text 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="strikeout text-style">S̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶T̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶3̶</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-style {color:blue;}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but, the actual text should not be stricked out.