# Strikethrough text in Select Option

Tags: html, css, forms, select

Does anyone know how to create a form select, where the front-end text that appears in the options has a strikethrough? We want to show how prices are being discounted for a sale, so want to be able to basically do:

```
<option value="10"><strike>$15</strike> $10</option>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could have the effect using CSS for all of the option's text but I don't know offhand of any way to do it for only some of the text.

Comment: You can have a look at this answer. It should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083426/strikeout-text-in-select-option

Comment: Yes, I saw the post about striking all the text, but I need a way to only strike through part of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't give any css formatting to that option tag. Usually, when you want a different style in the selector options you need to create your own select with css and js.
Here you have a reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp